# Variable declaration in startup.m not working in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, startup

I'm trying to declare some magic number constants which I need to access in every script. I made a file `load_constants.m` in `my_path` which looks like:

```
magic_number = 10;
other_magic_number = 12;
```

My `startup.m` looks like this:

```
% add a bunch of packages
addpath ~/Documents/MATLAB/some-package

userpath(my_path)
load_constants
```

But when I try to access `magic_number` in the Command Window:

```
Undefined function or variable 'magic_number'.
```

Directly declaring the variables in `startup.m` doesn't work either. How to fix this?

Comment: Is your `startup.m` located in MATLAB's Current Directory?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is normal behavior, `startup.m` is a function and variables declare inside the function are **local** to that function (and then vanish when going out of the scope):

```
function [] = startup()
%[
    magic_number = 10; %% This is local variable
%]
```

Use the [`assignin`](http://fr.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/assignin.html) function to have `magic_number` to be visible from the  `base` workspace:

```
function [] = startup()
%[
    assignin('base', 'magic_number', 10); % This value will be visible from 'base' workspace
%]
```

Note that for having `magic_number` value visible not only to scripts but functions also, it may better to create a `magic_number.m` function and add it to your path:

```
function [v] = magic_number()
%[
    v = 10;
%]
```

which can be called without the brackets (i.e. just like the syntax for variables)

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. Functions seemed too unwieldy earlier, but I realised it is probably the best options. I've placed them all in a `Constants` folder, which I've added to my path.

Comment: Based on the code the user has posted, it's a script not a function.